# Convergence to O(1)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

Could someone please explain $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^i= 1 + 2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^1 + 3\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \ldots$ converges to $O(1)$ as per my algorithmns lecturer. Thank you

Comment: apply $\sum nx^{n-1}=\frac d{dx}\sum x^n=\frac d{dx}\frac 1{1-x}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$ with $x=\frac12$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an [Arithmetico–geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence). We have
$$
{\displaystyle \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\color {blue}k}{\color {green}r^{k}}={\frac {r}{(1-r)^{2}}},\quad \mathrm {for\ } 0<r<1}
$$
Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 2):

Recall a sequence is $O(1)$ if and only if it is *bounded*. So asking for a sum to be $O(1)$ is asking for its sequence of partial sums to be bounded. Since every summand is positive, this is asking that the sum is *convergent*.

So saying this sum is $O(1)$ is asking for it to be convergent. Of course, we can see this sum converges since (as noted in the comment), your sum is

$$\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^2} = 4 = O(1)$$

Said another way:

$$
S_n = 
\sum_{i < n} (i+1) \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^i \leq
\sum_{i < \infty} (i+1) \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^i =
4 = O(1)
$$

So the sequence of partial sums is $O(1)$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^